# File Explorer - Open in MS Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-file-explorer

Good day.  I have a requirement to move from IE 11 to MS Edge on our systems, with all functionality as well.  Currently, users will log into the computer, IE will launch with a local HTML file - User Dashboard, and then select which button on the page they want to use.  Some of these buttons are linked to PDF files, some open File Explorer so that it opens their 'working directory' and/or file explorer to another directory on the machine for them to work in.  They also run .lnk / .ps1 files.  Works like a charm.

I was able to get about 80% of the functionality working using the Edge GPO template but now the only thing missing is opening file explorer for them to use the above situations.  Currently when they click on the button on the page - file:/// - it opens up a new tab that displays the directory it is linked to.  Unfortunately they are not able to run .lnk / .ps1 / .bat files.  When selected, they open up in a new tab with the code displayed.

Is there anyway to run a program from Edge?  I've already set the following in the GPO:

LGPO - Administrative Template -> MS Edge -> Allow launching of local files in internet explorer mode -> Enabled (default -> Not Configured)

LGPO - Administrative Template -> MS Edge ->< Configure Internet Explorer Integration -> Enabled -> IE Mode (default - Not Configured)

LGPO - Administrative Template -> MS Edge -> Open Local Files in Internet Explorer Mode file extensions allowed -> Enabled - "*" (default - Not Configured)

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I agree with K J's answer. There's no way to run the files you mentioned in modern browsers due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to run a program from Edge?

Generally no, Edge used to be able to run epub files but even that feature is now removed.

Basically you can run any file type that is readable within Edge so txt or xml or htm or svg or mp4 etc.

When browsing local system in reader mode you can navigate up and down folders** local or on server and click any readable file type, however LNK files will behave in different ways.

LNK files that invoke an svg or txt or other Edge text safe readable object will open that readable bat cmd wsh ps1 file in a tab if necessary.

LNK files that call an executable such as notepad calc cmd or anything like a .hta runtime file count as not readable and are treated as requiring a security response, so will invoke an extra security step asking if you wish to download a copy.

You can download a copy of notepad.exe or cmd.exe but it will then run raw so runs outside EDGE and thus a copy of CMD.exe will simply open the console  or a copy of notepad will open with a blank page. Only a copy of a stub.exe that does not need arguments would be useful.

** A zip folder normally operable in File Explorer counts as a downloadable security risk inside Edge.